# two cubes dont see in window how to fix

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, orthographic

I try to draw 2 cubes which are auto rotating but I don't see this cubes. Does anybody now how to fix this?

In addition, I want to add a camera to this program. Could you help me with doing this?

[image]

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1920
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 1080

void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
void DrawCube(GLfloat centerPosX, GLfloat centerPosY, GLfloat centerPosZ, GLfloat edgeLength);

GLfloat rotationX = 0.0f;
GLfloat rotationY = 0.0f;
GLfloat rtri;               // Angle For The Triangle ( NEW )
GLfloat rquad;

int main(void)
{ 
    GLFWwindow *window;

    // Initialize the library
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, 1);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth, screenHeight); // specifies the part of the window to which OpenGL will draw (in pixels), convert from normalised to pixels
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // projection matrix defines the properties of the camera that views the objects in the world coordinate frame. Here you typically set the zoom factor, aspect ratio and the near and far clipping planes
    glLoadIdentity(); // replace the current matrix with the identity matrix and starts us a fresh because matrix transforms such as glOrpho and glRotate cumulate, basically puts us at (0, 0, 0)
    glOrtho(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 1000); // essentially set coordinate system
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // (default matrix mode) modelview matrix defines how your objects are transformed (meaning translation, rotation and scaling) in your world
    glLoadIdentity(); // same as above comment

    GLfloat halfScreenWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
    GLfloat halfScreenHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;


    // Loop until the user closes the window
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glClearColor(0.6f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f);
        glClearDepth(1.0f);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            // Enables Depth Testing
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                             // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
        glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

        // Render OpenGL here
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glPushMatrix();
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);   
        glRotatef(rtri, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);// Move Left 1.5 Units And Into The Screen 6.0
        DrawCube(halfScreenWidth, halfScreenHeight, -500, 200);
        glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Current Modelview Matrix
        glTranslatef(1.5f, 0.0f, -7.0f);
        glRotatef(rquad, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        DrawCube(halfScreenWidth, halfScreenHeight, -500, 200);
        glPopMatrix();
        rtri += 0.2f;                                           // Increase The Rotation Variable For The Triangle ( NEW )
        rquad -= 0.15f;

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}



void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    //std::cout << key << std::endl;

    const GLfloat rotationSpeed = 10;

    // actions are GLFW_PRESS, GLFW_RELEASE or GLFW_REPEAT
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS || action == GLFW_REPEAT)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
        case GLFW_KEY_UP:
            rotationX -= rotationSpeed;
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_DOWN:
            rotationX += rotationSpeed;
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT:
            rotationY += rotationSpeed;
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_LEFT:
            rotationY -= rotationSpeed;
            break;
        }


    }
}


void DrawCube(GLfloat centerPosX, GLfloat centerPosY, GLfloat centerPosZ, GLfloat edgeLength)
{
    GLfloat halfSideLength = edgeLength * 0.5f;

    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f, // triangle 1 : begin
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // triangle 1 : end
        1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, // triangle 2 : begin
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, // triangle 2 : end
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
    };
    static const GLfloat g_color_buffer_data[] = {
        0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
        0.609f,  0.115f,  0.436f,
        0.327f,  0.483f,  0.844f,
        0.822f,  0.569f,  0.201f,
        0.435f,  0.602f,  0.223f,
        0.310f,  0.747f,  0.185f,
        0.597f,  0.770f,  0.761f,
        0.559f,  0.436f,  0.730f,
        0.359f,  0.583f,  0.152f,
        0.483f,  0.596f,  0.789f,
        0.559f,  0.861f,  0.639f,
        0.195f,  0.548f,  0.859f,
        0.014f,  0.184f,  0.576f,
        0.771f,  0.328f,  0.970f,
        0.406f,  0.615f,  0.116f,
        0.676f,  0.977f,  0.133f,
        0.971f,  0.572f,  0.833f,
        0.140f,  0.616f,  0.489f,
        0.997f,  0.513f,  0.064f,
        0.945f,  0.719f,  0.592f,
        0.543f,  0.021f,  0.978f,
        0.279f,  0.317f,  0.505f,
        0.167f,  0.620f,  0.077f,
        0.347f,  0.857f,  0.137f,
        0.055f,  0.953f,  0.042f,
        0.714f,  0.505f,  0.345f,
        0.783f,  0.290f,  0.734f,
        0.722f,  0.645f,  0.174f,
        0.302f,  0.455f,  0.848f,
        0.225f,  0.587f,  0.040f,
        0.517f,  0.713f,  0.338f,
        0.053f,  0.959f,  0.120f,
        0.393f,  0.621f,  0.362f,
        0.673f,  0.211f,  0.457f,
        0.820f,  0.883f,  0.371f,
        0.982f,  0.099f,  0.879f
    };


    //glColor3f( colour[0], colour[1], colour[2] );
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, g_vertex_buffer_data);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, g_color_buffer_data);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}</i>
```

Comment: Are you sure your cubes aren't just very tiny? Since you draw them with a side length of 2 they should be 2x2 pixels with your current projection. The first cube will also be off-screen since the x coordinates range from -2.5 to -0.5. The second part of the question (about the camera) is also too broad. What have you tried there, what didn't work?

Comment: oh. thank how to fix this? how to chage coordinates range? how to chage size cube. sorry its my first program and so many i dont know=(

Comment: Here you can have done up to 10 different mistakes..depth buffer: clear and test, object positioning, backface culling, ..I strongly suggest you to work step by step from a simple triangle example. Change the triangle in a cube, then translate it, then use the depth buffer...and enjoy the trip.

Comment: ok thank u i try it=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I recommend to put the origin of your [Orthographic Projection Matrix](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html#ortho) in the center of the viewport:

```
glOrtho(-SCREEN_WIDTH*0.5,  SCREEN_WIDTH*0.5,
        -SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.5, SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.5,
        0.0, 1000.0);
```

The Model-View matrix constis of the view matrix and the model matrix.
While the view matrix describes how you look at the scene, the model matrix describes the location of your geometry in the scene.

For the View-Matrix you choosed the identity matrix.

For the model matrix you did set up the rotations correctly. You also calculated the translational and the scale of the model, but you never used it.
You missed to translate and scale your Model-View matrix before drawing.

```
GLfloat halfScreenWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.5;
GLfloat halfScreenHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.5;

GLfloat sideLenght = 200.0f;
GLfloat halfSideLenght = sideLenght * 0.5;

while ( ... )
{
    ...

    // backup the view matrix
    glPushMatrix();

    // set up the model matrix
    glTranslatef(-0.5f * halfScreenWidth, 0.0f, -6.0f);         // translate the model   
    glRotatef(rtri, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                          // rotate the model
    glScalef( halfSideLenght, halfSideLenght, halfSideLenght ); // scale the model

    // draw the 1. cube
    DrawCube(/* I removed the parameter here, because they are not used */);

    // restor the view matrix
    glPopMatrix();

    // backup the view matrix
    glPushMatrix();

    // set up the model matrix
    glTranslatef(0.5f * halfScreenWidth, 0.0f, -7.0f);          // translate the model
    glRotatef(rquad, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                         // rotate the model
    glScalef( halfSideLenght, halfSideLenght, halfSideLenght ); // scale the model

    // draw the 2. cube
    DrawCube(/* I removed the parameter here, because they are not used */);

    // restor the view matrix
    glPopMatrix();

  ...
}
```